# can we manipulate the default behaviour of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property in spring boot?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have this weird query on hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property, like can we control the behaviour of this property once its value has been set to create. I mean you have set this property value to 'create' which will apparently drop all the tables and recreate them. But what i want to do us i need to make sure whether if table exists it should not drop it.

I know that i can use 'update' rather than 'create' but out of curiosity wanted to know whether one can manipulate this behaviour in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. You can not manipulate it's behaviour. Every attribute and value is defined for serving specific purpose.

Comment: Thanks Alien,  but say there is this usecase where you need to insert/delete records for one table(Content table) and you want to run an simple select query to another table(Filestore table). But the Content table data can be manipulated but you should not do any changes to Filestore table, so if you set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property value as create then first it obviously drop two of them which i dont want. So can we achieve this usecase.

Comment: Alien so you are suggesting to use 'update' rather 'create' which i got, but why exactly you are referring spring runner  or @postconstruct as i know they involve in spring life cycle which will allow you to run some code before or after application start/end.